# Accessing the 'id' value from the side menu example from the Iconic framework using AngularJS and

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iconic

With the Iconic Framework side menu example how do I access the 'id' and 'Title' value from the controller?

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {$scope.playlists = [
{ title: 'Traffic', id: 1 },
{ title: 'Litter', id: 2 },
{ title: 'Marine', id: 3 }]
```

In the Playlist.html template file?

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlist One">
 <ion-content>
  <h1>Playlist</h1>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The other relevant code from app.js file is:

```
.state('app.single', {
  url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
   views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/playlist.html",
      controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
    } 
  }
})
```

And the controller - I think:

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope) { 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Old Ans**

Its Simple. you just have to insure that in your Config you have assigned controller to the view.

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlist One">
 <ion-content>
 <h1>Playlist</h1>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in playlists">
     ID: {{p.id}}
  </li>
</ul>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Updated**

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlist One">
 <ion-content>
 <h1>Playlist</h1>
  <!-- Pass playlist as a parameter named **p** here onclick function-->
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in playlists" ng-click="selected(p)">
     ID: {{p.id}}
  </li>
</ul>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Your controller will look like this.Only you need to add **selected** function in your controller like this.

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope) { 

   $scope.selected=function(playlist){
     $scope.selectedPlaylist=playlist;
     console.log($scope.selectedPlaylist.id)
   }
 })
```

Comment: Sorry I know it sounds simple - but what does that code look like?

Comment: want to access selected item id ?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm after!

`.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope) {
})`

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `PlaylistsCtrl` to this `ion-view` from its `state` mentioned in `config` phase.

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlist One">
 <ion-content>
  <h1>Playlist</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
  Number: {{playlist.id}} | Title: {{playlist.title}}
  </div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Thanks - are you able to expand on that answer? I've added the state code in the original question.

Comment: @Vamsi let me check..don't comment like this on any answer..Thats bad